# How to insert a PNG without background to another PNG in PYVIPS?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, libvips

I have two png images with transparent background

example:

[image: image_0]

[image: image_1]

and I'm trying to achieve something similar to the PIL `paste()` function in pyvips, where I can merge two images and 'remove the transparent background' using a mask.

PIL example:

```
image = Image.open(filepath, 'r')
image_2 = Image.open(filepath, 'r')
image.paste(image_2, (50, 50), mask=mask)
```

**Expected Result**:

[image: expected result]

I've already tried to use the pyvips `insert()` function, but both images retain their backgrounds.

Pyvips insert:

```
image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(path, access='sequential')
image_2 = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(path, access='sequential')
image = image.insert(image_2, 50,50)
```

**Pyvips Result:**

[image: pyvips result]

How can I have the "expected result" with pyvips?

Comment: Please provide representative images and expected result.

Comment: Added the images as example @MarkSetchell

Comment: I realize this isn't what you're asking about, but as an aside, in PIL you could use alpha composite instead of paste and then you wouldn't need a mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, using the `composite()` function:

```
import pyvips

# Load background and foreground images
bg = pyvips.Image.new_from_file('WA8rm.png', access='sequential')
fg = pyvips.Image.new_from_file('Ny50t.png', access='sequential')

# Composite foreground over background and save result
bg.composite(fg, 'over').write_to_file('result.png')
```

[image]

---

If you want to add an offset in x and y, use:

```
bg.composite(fg, 'over', x=200, y=100).write_to_file('result.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Can i still give `(50, 50)` as position?

Comment: I have updated my post, please see new addition at bottom.